# run mvn integration tests in async

Tags: java, maven

I am running integration tests on my java app.

here is my code:

```
public class MyClassIT {

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    setUp();
}

@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    doTheIntegration(1);
}

@Test
public void test2() throws Exception {
    doTheIntegration(2);
}

@Test
public void test3() throws Exception {
    doTheIntegration(3);
}

private static void doTheIntegration(int i) {
    System.out.println("started--" + i);
    doSomethingLongerThan1Minute();
    System.out.println("done--" + i);
}


@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    tearDown();

}

}
```

here is the pom failsafe plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCount>10</threadCount>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I am running `mvn verify` and expecting all 3 tests to happen async
but they are running in synchronize

```
$ mvn verify
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.example.MyClassIT

 started--1
 done--1
 started--2
 done--2
 started--3
 done--3
```

how can I make them run async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/junit.html) From JUnit 4.7 onwards you can run your tests in parallel

make sure junit dependency is set to the right version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
    </dependency>
```